# iText: Table(com.​lowagie.​text) created only occupies 80% of the entire page , How to make it utilise the entire page

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am writing the following code in order to create a PDF file with a table in it.

```
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 80);
        Font myfont = new Font(FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 13, Font.NORMAL));
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(request.getRealPath("/") + "SAMPLE.pdf"));

        document.open();
        Table table = new Table(2);
        Cell c2 = new Cell();

        int[] widths = {8, 150}; //Tried different values, but no change
        table.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
        table.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        table.setSpacing(0);
        table.setPadding(0);
        table.setTableFitsPage(true); //Tried with 'false', even removed it, but no change
        table.setWidths(widths);

        c2 = new Cell(new Paragraph("1.     ", myfont));
        c2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table.addCell(c2);
        c2 = new Cell(new Paragraph("TEST DATA     ", myfont));
        c2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table.addCell(c2);

        c2 = new Cell(new Paragraph("2.     ", myfont));
        c2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table.addCell(c2);
        c2 = new Cell(new Paragraph("TEST DATA", myfont));
        c2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table.addCell(c2);

        c2 = new Cell(new Paragraph("3.     ", myfont));
        c2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table.addCell(c2);
        c2 = new Cell(new Paragraph("TEST DATA", myfont));
        c2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        table.addCell(c2);

        document.add(table);
        document.close();
```

But the file created contains a table that occupies around 80-85% of the page. I want it to utilise the entire page.

I tried making some adjustments to the code like changing the `table.setTableFitsPage(true);` to `table.setTableFitsPage(false);` and even tried removing it.
also altered around with the widths assigned. But in vain as in all cases it only gave me the file with a table occupying only 80-85% of page.

Is there something I am missing to add to my code or is there an attribute that is stopping the Table from taking up 100% of page.

It creates problem when the content is large as I end up getting long tables with spaces on the page still unoccupied.

**Attached a screen-shot of the actual PDF file generated here!**

[Screen-shot of the PDF generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GngCq.png)

Comment: Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: I am using **itext-2.1.5.jar**

Comment: In that case I first recommend upgrading to the latest version (5.0.6 at the moment). Head over to http://itextpdf.com/download.php for downloads. The latest version will contain many improvements and bug fixes compared to the version you're using, plus you're much more likely to get support from sites like this (as there is more people using the most recent than a very old version of the library).

Comment: Well the last version that supported the Tables was 2.17 after which itext jumped directly to 5.0.x version. The 5.0.0 version **removed** the Table and other table related features... check it here at [itext (History) of 5.0.0](http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=50&node=500) you will find it mentioned in last couple of lines.... that is reason I am working in the 2.1.5 version....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite your table code to use [PdfPTable](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPTable.html) instead.  You can find some [examples of its use online](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=4).  The entire 4th chapter of iText in Action 2nd ed is about tables, PdfPTables to be precise.

Lots of example code.  Enjoy.

Comment: Well, I had tried using PdfPTable before posting this question but even that didn't help, later on just casually I had a look at one of the examples of **PdfPTable** [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=93), where I saw that when we add the attribute `table.setWidthPercentage(100f);` to the code the table uses 100% of page, after that just gave the 'Table' a try and added this to my code `table.setWidth(100f)` and gave the widths as relative to 100(i.e. sum of all values adding up to 100) and that did the trick.

Comment: As you have been closely associated with the iText api, I want to ask, **Why was the Tables and its other features removed from the iText 5.x.x versions?** I think tabular structures are essential part of iText and the tables are often used when creating PDfs..

Comment: The CLASS `Table` was removed.  `PdfPTable` is far more flexible/powerful.  Use it instead.  And there was no need for a generic "Table" because we only output to PDF these days.  And no, we don't need a generic much-of-anything-else, but most Entities don't have a superior replacement sitting around in the .pdf package somewhere.  Table did.

Comment: PS: I think we should have deprecated it rather than yanking it entirely, but it wasn't my call to make.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PdfPTable class instead, and you can set the column widths on the entire table. Making it span the entire page can be done by constructing a

```
float delta = document.getPageSize().getWidth() / numberOfColumns;
// add delta numberOfColumn times
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[] {delta, delta, delta, delta });
table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
```

The widths passed in the constructor determine how much space a given column gets relative to the width of the entire table.

Comment: Thank you...but I think that is what Mark also suggested, there was no need to repeat...anyways....I had checked it out and I also solved the issue by using the simple **Table** itself....have added how I did that in a comment above....Please check it...